# Javasript array functions with no arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

This is more like a silly question but I have to ask it.
It is a good practice to call an array function like map without arguments?
Let's say I already have an array 'x' on my code with a specified length and I want to make another array with the same length but with different content.
For example:

```
function generateRandomContent() { ... }
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const y = x.map(() => generateRandomContent())
// or
const z = Array(x.length).fill().map(() => { ... })
```

Of course I could pass an argument and never use it, but it is there a good way and a bad way to do it?

Comment: Why would you want to do a mapping operation if it's not dependent on anything but the size of the initial array?

Comment: `.map()` is not supposed to be used without arguments. You could use `.forEach()` instead or a for loop.

Comment: `Array.from({length: x.length}, () => someFn())` or even `Array.from({length: x.length}, someFn)` will generate an array as the same *size* with different contents. `.map` signifies that the content of the new array is closely related to the content of the original array.

Comment: Maybe it's worth considering `Array.from`, which takes a function as its second argument. E.g.: `Array.from(Array(10), generateRandomContent)`.

Comment: @Yousername `forEach` makes even less sense there.

Comment: @VLAZ Please copy those two comments into an answer :-)

Comment: Why don't pass the x len and work with it? There is no use for a the map() method in your case.

Comment: @VLAZ that's why I asked for, I just wanted to generate another array with the same length as my first array, I didn't knew how to do it, your solution makes more sense. I already tried using map with no arguments and is working just fine but as you said makes no sense mapping an array without using its contents. I didn't knew `Array.from()` accepts a second argument. Anyway if you want to post your comment as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here. A *mapping* operation is when you take some input and generate a new output. So you have a relation that looks like this `x -> y` for a single element, then you apply it to the entire array to generate a new array using the same mapping rule:

```js
const input = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100];

//mapping relationship
const toCharacter = x => String.fromCharCode(x);

const result = input.map(toCharacter);

console.log(result.join(''))
```

If you just want to create a new array based on the *length* of the original but with totally unrelated content, then you are better off to use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) which can create an array with a given size and takes a second argument that will fill it with content:

```js
function generateRandomContent() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const y = Array.from({length: x.length}, () => generateRandomContent());
//or just pass the function reference
const z = Array.from({length: x.length}, generateRandomContent);


console.log(y);
console.log(z);
```